# Angular 5 & Rxjs: Wait for all subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

I would like to wait for all my http request to be completed before doing something.

Before Angular 5, I was using promises and `Promise.All`.

With Angular 5 and the new `HttpClient`, I transformed my promises into observables. If I understand correctly, I now have to use `forkJoin` to replace the `Promise.All`.

But this is a problem because `forkJoin` expect Observables as parameters, but I already subscribe to those in the code

```
ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin([this.getTemplates(), this.getHistory()]).subscribe(
        results => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    );
}

getTemplates(): Observable<any> {

    return this.notifService.getTemplateList()
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.code === 0) {
                    this.templateList = response.data;
                }
                else {
                    this.openSnackBar(response.formatError());
                }
            },
            error => {
                this.openSnackBar(error);
            });
}
```

I can't do the logic inside the subscription of the `forkJoin` because those method (`getTemplates()` & `getHistory()`) need to be standalone and called seperatly in other processes.

So, what can I do to be sure that all the subscriptions are done ?

By the way, the code above doesn't compile because the method `getTemplates()` return a `Subscription` and not an `Observable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` Instead of `subscribe` in `getTemplates`:

```
getTemplates(): Observable<any> {
    return this.notifService.getTemplateList()
        .map(response => {
            /* ... */
            return reponse;
        });
}
```

Comment: but subscribe is a best way to use, once the data is ready you can load the data to component

Comment: If I want to call `getTemplates()` elsewhere, I'll have to subscribe to it then, right ? Otherwhise the call will not be done. `getTemplates().subscribe()`

Comment: [check this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncpgp3) how powerful subscription is

Comment: @Faly  Please can you explain why "map" solves the problem? I believe "map" returns an Observable and you still need to subscribe to it to get the result. How does it solve the problem of template not rendering before the data is available?