# RXJS Angular - How to call a function at end of foreach loop that contains observables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular5, angular-httpclient

```
this.attachmentList.forEach((attachment, i) => {
    this.service.getPageOfAttachment().flatMap(response =>
        this.service.download((JSON.parse(response['Content']).mediaUrl)))
        .subscribe(response => {
            }, error => (console.log(error)),
            () => {
                if (i > this.attachmentList.length - 1) this.getPdfSharp(pdfSharpByteArray, attachment.entityName, i);
            })
})
```

At the end of the foreach loop I'm checking the value of "i" and if it's greater than the list length, I call the function.  The problem with this is that since I'm subscribing inside the loop, the value of I is not always in the correct order and the function is called early.  How can I iterate through a foreach loop with the subscriptions inside, then call my function when the loop and subscriptions are complete?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of `forkJoin`? Might not be the cleanest but I think it can work. Also this can help [waiting observable subscribe inside foreach to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721283/waiting-observable-subscribe-inside-foreach-to-end)

Answer (score 0):

check the below code..

```
const _subscriptions = [];
  Observable.of(this.attachmentList)
    .subscribe((attachments) => {
      _subscriptions = attachments.map(element1 => {
        this.service.getPageOfAttachment()
          .flatMap(response => this.service.download((JSON.parse(response['Content']).mediaUrl)))
          .subscribe(response => { },
            error => (console.log(error)),
            completed => (console.log("completed...!!!")));
      });
    });
  Promise.all(_subscriptions)
    .then(() => {

        this.getPdfSharp(pdfSharpByteArray, attachment.entityName, i);
    });
```