# ForEach wait for Observable Subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, observable

I have this array `orderCodes` that has the codes for specific orders, and then with the code I can get the details of that order (each order has multiple products), and I need to extract the code of each product inside the order details.

The `getOrderDetails()`is an `Observable` with `results`(an array of the products), and each `result`has a `code` which is what I need.

```
    this.orderCodes.forEach((orderCode) => {

      loadOrderDetails(orderCode);

      getOrderDetails().subscribe((order: any) => {
        if (order.results) {
          order.results.map((result) => {
            console.log(result.code);
          });
        }
      });

    });
```

I've tried with this `forEach` but since I'm subscribing to the `Observable` the forEach skips to the next iteration and I need it to wait

Any ideas?

Comment: The question isn't clear at the moment. What is `loadOrderDetails()` doing? How is it related to `getOrderDetails()`. Instead of trying to explain verbally it'd be much quicker if you could provide the implementation details and the result expected of each step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [waiting observable subscribe inside foreach to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721283/waiting-observable-subscribe-inside-foreach-to-end)

Answer (score 1):

rxjs way would be

```
from(this.orderCodes).pipe(
  concatMap((orderCode) =>  // concatMap operator makes your items come "in order" one after another
    defer(() => {
      loadOrderDetails(orderCode);

      return getOrderDetails();

    }))
).subscribe((order: any) => {
  if (order.results) {
    order.results.map((result) => {
      console.log(result.code);
    });
  }
});
```

or you could convert to promises and use async await (more elegant, but usually less prefered way in angular because of converting to promises and change detection issues if done wrong, but it depends...)

```
async myFunctionThatDoesAllThis(...) {
....
for(let orderCode of this.orderCodes) {
  loadOrderDetails();
  const order = await getOrderDetails().pipe(take(1)).toPromise(); // pipe(take(1)) could be skipped if getOrderDetails is just an http request.
  if(order.results) {
     order.results.forEach((result) => {
        console.log(result.code);
     });
  }
}
```